# dijit/Dialog sets height on small window sizes

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo

I have a dijit/Dialog that displays normally at browser window sizes >1102px, but at sizes smaller than that it behaves abnormally. I've figured out that the reason for this is that the JS is adding fixed heights and smaller browser widths (as well as some additional absolute positioning on children nodes). Can someone explain why this exists or how to prevent it from setting those heights/absolute positionings (preferrably without just having to use !important styling everywhere). Or, am I misreading and there is another reason that is happening?

I was able to make a plunker showing that this happens. If you load it when the plunker widget is <1105px you will see a fixed height when you look in dev tools, but if you load it when the plunker is >1105px you will not see a fixed height.

https://plnkr.co/edit/JCY0qRzXPIwNIAUgVOFM?p=preview

```
require (['dojo/parser', 'dojo/domReady', 'dijit/Dialog'],
function (parser, ready, Dialog) {
    ready(function () {
       var dialog = new Dialog({title: "Random Title", style: 'width: 990px;'});
       dialog.set("content", "hello");
       dialog.show();
       parser.parse();
   });
   return {};
});
```

**Note**: You have to reload (stop then run) the plunker to reload the dialog at the new browser width. Just changing the browser size while the dialog is open will not cause the fixed height to show up/disappear

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html#sizing-the-dialog) says:

> A dialog by default sizes itself according to its content, just like a plain `<div>`. If the contents are too large for the screen, then Dialog will automatically add a scrollbar.
>
> Therefore, you usually shouldn’t need to set an explicit size for a dialog. If you do want to, then you need to add width/height to a div *inside* the dialog, or set a size on the .dijitDialogPaneContent div:

Your example sets width property on Dialog, how to set it *inside* is shown in [this example](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html#terms-and-conditions-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problème you can use the dialog css property to fix the width size as blow snippet :

```
.dijitLayoutContainer {
  width: 990px !important;
}
// set some spacing from parent
.dijitDialogTitleBar,.dijitDialogPaneContent {
  width: 980px !important;
}
```

above a working snippet

```js
require (['dojo/parser', 'dojo/domReady', 'dijit/Dialog'],
function (parser, ready, Dialog) {
    ready(function () {
       var dialog = new Dialog({title: "Random Title", style: 'width: 990px;'});
       dialog.set("content", "hello");
       dialog.show();
       parser.parse();
   });
   return {};
});
```

```css
.dijitLayoutContainer {
  width: 990px !important;
}
/*to make spacing right nd left  */
.dijitDialogTitleBar,.dijitDialogPaneContent {
  width: 980px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
  
</body>
```